# how to show messages and image in uitableviewcell in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I am working on chat application. Actually i have 3 arrays. First array stores **user name** and second array stores **chat message** and third array stores **images**. I am picking image from photo gallery.

When user sends any message to the chat wall I display message in bubble.

So I'm writing some conditions like the below:

- if `arr2` value is not null then displaying chat message
- if `arr3` value is not null displaying image in chat bubble
- if `arr2` value is `null` then i want to hide `lbldesc` and show only `imv` gallery image
- if `arr3` value is `null` then hide imv gallery image and enable `lblDesc`

But i got exception like this:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** NSAllocateMemoryPages(4294967295) failed'`

Here is my code:

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cellIdentifier";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];

if (cell == nil) {

cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

}

cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

if (itemsDataArr.count>0) {

UIImageView  *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(35, 3, 250, 80)];

imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"speech-bubble-2-hi.png"];

imgView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;

imgView.tag = 5;

[cell.contentView addSubview:imgView];

NSArray *arr1=[[NSArray alloc]init];

arr1=[itemsUserNameArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSString *strval=[arr1 objectAtIndex:0];

lblTitle=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 5, 150, 20)];

lblTitle.highlightedTextColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

[cell.contentView addSubview:lblTitle];

[lblTitle setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14]];

lblTitle.text=strval;

[imgView addSubview:lblTitle];

NSArray *arr2=[[NSArray alloc]init];

arr2=[itemsDataArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSArray *arr3=[[NSArray alloc]init];

arr3=[itemImgArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if(![arr2 isEqual:@""])

{

NSString *strmsg=[arr2 objectAtIndex:0];

lblDesc=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 22, 300, 20)];

lblDesc.highlightedTextColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

lblDesc.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];

[cell.contentView addSubview:lblDesc];

[lblDesc setHidden:NO];

lblDesc.text=strmsg;

[imgView addSubview:lblDesc];

// imv.hidden=YES;

// [imv setHidden:true];

}

arr3=[itemImgArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if(![arr3 isEqual:nil])

{

NSString *strImg=[arr3 objectAtIndex:0];

NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[NSData                                     dataFromBase64String:strImg]];

//Now data is decoded. You can convert them to UIImage

imv = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(93,12, 50, 50)];

imv.image=[UIImage imageWithData:data];

[imgView addSubview:imv];

[lblDesc setHidden:YES];

// lblDesc.hidden=YES;

}

}

return cell;

}
```

Comment: @Signare hi if you have any idea plz tell me

Comment: @Signare actually only displaying image in chat bubble.. but if user sends any text message that is not showing app getting crash.

Comment: I guess, this could be the issue with image size @satya. Try to resize them.

Comment: @SatishA actually i got issue in if conditions..i am able to displaying only image in chat bubble if user pick the image from gallery.. if user sends the text message app getting crash

Comment: @SatishA yes bro.. plz create chat room i want to talk to you.. issue related thing...plz

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116155/discussion-between-satya-and-satish-a).

Answer (score 2):

I've used `PTSMessagingCell` from [here](https://github.com/ppanopticon/PTSMessagingCell/):

I've used `messages` array for texts/images. This is a ruf sample that may help you.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "PTSMessagingCell.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSMutableArray *messages;
    UITextView *sendMsg;
    UITableView *chatTable;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    messages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Hello",[UIImage imageNamed:@"download.jpeg"],@"Check This Out", nil];

    chatTable = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-100)];
    chatTable.delegate = self;
    chatTable.dataSource = self;
    chatTable.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.view addSubview:chatTable];
    chatTable.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];


    sendMsg = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, chatTable.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width-100, 100)];
    sendMsg.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    sendMsg.delegate = self;
    sendMsg.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    sendMsg.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0f;
    [self.view addSubview:sendMsg];

    UIButton *sendMsgbtn = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(sendMsg.frame.size.width, chatTable.frame.size.height, 100, 100)];
    [sendMsgbtn setTitle:@"SEND" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    sendMsgbtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [sendMsgbtn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [sendMsgbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(sendClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:sendMsgbtn];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapReceived:)];
    [tapGestureRecognizer setDelegate:self];
    [chatTable addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
}

-(void)sendClicked{
    [sendMsg resignFirstResponder];
    [chatTable reloadData];
}

#pragma mark - TableView Delegate and DataSource Methods

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [messages count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    /*This method sets up the table-view.*/

    static NSString* cellIdentifier = @"messagingCell";
    PTSMessagingCell * cell = (PTSMessagingCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[PTSMessagingCell alloc] initMessagingCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([[messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isKindOfClass:[UIImage class]]) {
        return [(UIImage *)[messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] size].height;
    }
    else{
        const char *jsonString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] UTF8String];
        NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithBytes:jsonString length:strlen(jsonString)];
        NSString *goodMsg = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
        CGSize messageSize = [PTSMessagingCell messageSize:goodMsg];
        NSLog(@"%f",messageSize.height + 2*[PTSMessagingCell textMarginVertical] + 40.0f);
        return messageSize.height + 2*[PTSMessagingCell textMarginVertical] + 40.0f;
    }

}

-(void)configureCell:(id)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (messages.count>0) {
        PTSMessagingCell* ccell = (PTSMessagingCell*)cell;

        if ([[messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isKindOfClass:[UIImage class]]) {

            ccell.sent = YES;
            ccell.avatarImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
            ccell.messageLabel.text = @"";
        }
        else{
            ccell.sent = YES;

                            const char *jsonString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] UTF8String];
                            NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithBytes:jsonString length:strlen(jsonString)];
                            NSString *goodMsg = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];

            ccell.messageLabel.text = [messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }
        ccell.timeLabel.text = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:[NSDate date] dateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle timeStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];


        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapReceived:)];
        [tapGestureRecognizer setDelegate:self];
        [ccell addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
    }
}

-(void)tapReceived:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGestureRecognizer
{
    // do something, like dismiss your view controller, picker, etc., etc.
    [sendMsg resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: PTSMessagingCell class does not have messageSize method. How did you solve?

Comment: it is there @Sanket Pandya, "+(CGSize)messageSize:(NSString*)message" and
"+(UIImage*)balloonImage:(BOOL)sent isSelected:(BOOL)selected" and then he is adjusting image and message in 
"-(id)initMessagingCellWithReuseIdentifier:(NSString*)reuseIdentifier".

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom cell and load images in background thread will give better UI performance